# Can Redis save 30 TB data?

Tags: redis, bigdata

Redis is a good solution for my work, but the problem is Redis needs much memory to save data. And my data is too big. Is there some solution that I can save such big data? Can Redis compress these data to save? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you have 30TB RAM, or 30 machines with 1TB RAM, etc. Why you need to store it all in memory?

Comment: I understand. Because they think it is faster. By the way, do you know some other solutions? other database?

Comment: You need to work out what can be stored on disk and what needs to be in memory, and select a setup based on that. Its impossible to suggest a solution without knowing about the use case.

Comment: Kyoto tycoon might fit the use case, make sure you shard the data properly in lot of instances.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is, **YES**. Like [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4554496/chris-tanner), pointed out you would need 30TB RAM system or a distributed system with total of 30 TB RAM.

**BUT**

Effective way to use redis is to use it as a cache store, otherwise you could have used any NOSQL database for BIG data like yours. Why would you need 30TB data in cache? Instead, you can try one of the following approach,

- Store the actual content/data on disk and store the index of data in redis. You can use [secondary indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) by redis.
- Encode/Compress your data using any loss-less compression technique and then store in redis. Redis will not compress data for you.

Comment: "Redis is a cache store". Contradicted by redis.io :)

Comment: Hi, I am very interested in secondary indexes. Could you help me take an simple example? I want to save many urls into redis, each url has an unique id. For example, "www.google.com  1", when I query "www.google.com", it can return 1. Is that possible to create secondary indexes? :)

Comment: @hobbs This is what I want to do, and the data is approximately 30TB.

Comment: @Cocoa3338 Share what you have read, understood and tried. We can help you after that.

Comment: @Abhishek After I know that the original method does not work(using Redis to save data directly), because it occupied too much memory, I have no choice, the original file is too big. But I think Redis is good because it can return the result what I want if it can load all the data successfully. But if I do not have 30 TB memory to save all the data, it means this method does not work. After you told me secondary indexes. I read something about it. But secondary indexes I think is used to relational data. For example,  hmset user:1 id "1" email "xesd@hotmail.com", we don't need all the data,

Comment: @Abhishek we just need part of data. so we create  zrange index? Did I understand correctly? But what I need to save is just "url id", no other information, both url and id I need. So I have no idea how to build index and make the usage of memory to save data decreasing. Our server only has few hundreds GB memory.

Comment: But I have no idea how he compressed the data

Comment: @Cocoa3338 Yes, you need to add index using `zadd` & then retrieve elements using `zrangebyscore` or `ZRANGE`

Comment: @Cocoa3338 You can compress data using any of the 3rd party open source compression tool like `7-zip` or you can create a compressor by yourself.

Comment: @Abhishek thanks, just want to make sure, if I compress the data, will it influence I query?

Comment: @Abhishek  But my supervisor told me, we can not compress a url.:( All the compression method is about json file.

Comment: You shouldn't compress the key, as you will be using it for indexing. The values has to be compressed. You can actually have a mapping of url with integer and index only integers and let urls be on disk. This way you will save lot of index memory as well.

Comment: @Abhishek in my case, I plan to save data to redis like this: ' 127.0.0.1:6379> hsetnx urlstore com,google)/ 1
(integer) 1 127.0.0.1:6379> hestnx urlstore com,google)/ 2
(error) ERR unknown command 'hestnx'
127.0.0.1:6379> hsetnx urlstore com,google)/ 2
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hsetnx urlstore com,facebook)/ 2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hsetnx urlstore de,bild)/ 3
(integer) 1'

Comment: The formatting in comments is not readable. Can you please add the info in question by editing it?